How to securely store an OAuth Client Secret provided by the user?
There's a web application which I'm creating integrations for, and one of those integrations makes use of a third-party API, which requires authentication through OAuth.
This basically requires that the user inputs their Client ID and Client Secret (which are derived from the user's personal account on the third-party's platform), in order to receive an access token for the API.
Unfortunately, the OAuth implementation that the API offers does NOT support a refresh token, which means I must have access to the Client Secret anytime the initial token expires.
Due to the web app's design, the user's input is in plaintext and always visible on the frontend, and storing anything with the word "secret" in plaintext is a big no-no.
I initially had the idea to encrypt the Client Secret using AES-256, and storing the encryption key server-side, but I'm not sure if this is a correct approach.

"Due to the web app's design, the user's input is in plaintext and always visible on the frontend" - the client secret has no business being exposed in client-side code, ever. It is meant to be used in API calls made from the server side only.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@C3roe I unfortunately cannot control the fact that the client secret is exposed on the client side. Additionally, the user is the one that must enter their client ID and secret to the web app. Would you recommend encryption in this case?

Is each user only supposed to access their "own" client? Or does user A input their client id & secret, and then other users B & C are supposed to use their
(A's) client? If it is the former, and you will only expose the secret to the user it "belongs" to, this might be okay; but if other people could get access to the client secret, then this is simply a no-go.

Yes, each user is only supposed to access their own client, other users cannot see another user's client in any way. Each user has their own client, users never share clients
